# Export to PDF with index bookmarks and unnumbered sections

Tags: org-mode, org-export, pdf

I want to export my .org file to pdf, with a table of contents. But I don't want the table of contents to be printed in the first page of the document.
Rather I want the table of contents to be embedded in the pdf file as bookmars. For example, see the figure:

[image]

How do I do this?

**Update:**

Currently the first lines of my .org file look like this:

```
#+OPTIONS: num:nil
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil
```

If I remove the `#+OPTIONS: num:nil` option, I get the desired PDF index (thanks @NickD). But then the sections get automatic numbers which I want to remove.

Is there a way to get the PDF index, and also remove section numbering?

Comment: isn't this just the way your reader presents navigation in the file? which means you probably want  `#+OPTIONS: toc:nil`

Comment: @manandearth It only works if the PDF file has the table of contents embedded. The viewer does not detect the headings automatically. But yes, I need `#+OPTIONS: toc:nil` to get rid of the table of contents in the first page of the document. Now I only need to get the table of contents embedded in the file. There is a way to do this in latex.

Comment: If you know how to do it in latex, perhaps you could put the right commands in a `#+BEGIN_EXPORT latex` block?

Comment: @rpluim I have seen it done in LaTeX, but right now it seems cannot find the correct command. I tried `#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{bookmark}` at the first line of my org file but nothing happens.

Comment: I thought this is handled by `hyperref` package: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42343/how-to-add-a-navigation-window-to-a-latex-generated-pdf-document

Comment: @wvxvw I still see no pdf index even using `hyperref`.

Comment: Following @manandearth's instructions, I get no TOC in the document but both xpdf and evince show the sectioning in the Outline sidebar. That's with hyperref included. Without hyperref, nothing shows up in the sidebar.

Comment: @NickD Exactly how did you include hyperref?

Comment: Nothing special: just what the latex exporter gave me. To test without, I just deleted the `\usepackage{hyperref}` and the `hypersetup{...}` from the produced TeX file.

Comment: @NickD So you export from org to LaTeX, not PDF?

Comment: I do `C-c l p` (export to LaTeX as PDF file).

Comment: @NickD Hmmm, I added the first lines of my .org file to my question (see edit). Can you please tell me what you are doing differently? Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83645/discussion-between-nickd-and-becko).

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I got it working. This produces the PDF index, no table of contents in the document, and no section numbering.

```
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil
#+LATEX: \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
```

Note that I am not using `#+OPTIONS: num:nil`, because for some reason this option breaks the PDF index. However `#+LATEX: \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` is a workaround to prevent section numbering.

Comment: Source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33696/no-section-numbers-but-still-have-pdf-bookmarks-with-hyperref

Comment: Very nice! I forgot that what you cannot do with org, you can do in latex.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can get rid of section numbers with `num:nil` and still get the index. As I explained in the chat, `num:nil` produces starred sections which latex treats as unnumbered sections. But then it also fails to add them to the `.aux` file as `\contentsline`s, so the PDF does not get any information that can be used to generate the index.

Comment: I got it working. See my answer. Thanks for your help!